# Enable Multiline for AddTextInput

Tags: grafana

I am writing my own plugin for Grafana and I want to display multiple lines (i.e. rows) for `addTextInput` so that I can write paragraphs of text in the textbox (i.e. like grafana's own Text Plugin's Content Input). By default, addTextInput only has a single row. This is something that should be pretty simple but somehow I can't find the feature in the documentation. Does anyone knows how to do it?

In **module.ts**:

```
return builder
    .addTextInput({
        path: 'myText',
        name: 'This is supposed to be a multiple line input',
        defaultValue: '',
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer after hours of googling and looking at the source code of others. This is the way to enable multiple rows on the textinput:

```
return builder
    .addTextInput({
        path: 'myText',
        name: 'This is supposed to be a multiple line input',
        defaultValue: '',
        settings: {
            useTextarea:true,
            rows: 5,
        }
    })
});
```

I'm not sure why isn't this documented in the documentation.